# Unable to execute Junit Test case for RestController containing update method?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit, mockito

While trying to write **Junit Test** case for the **controller** class containing **update** method, getting the error?

I have already written the **JUnit** test cases for the other methods, but when I tried to run the junit test case for **update** method I am getting the following error. **org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected: <"[{"title":"Hibernate with JPA","subject":"Java","publisher":"IGH Pubications","language":"English","numberOfPages":1532,"isbn":"EMP_6953_2019"}]">  but was:<"[ ]">**

LibraryController.java

```java
@PutMapping("/books/{isbn}")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> updateBook(@PathVariable String isbn, @Valid @RequestBody Book bookDetails) {
        log.info("Entering updateBook() method ");
        Book updatedBook = librarianService.updateBook(isbn, bookDetails);
        log.info("Exiting updateBook() method ");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedBook);
    }
```

The Junit Test case for the updateBook() method.
LibraryControllerTest.java

```java
@Test
    public void testUpdateBook() throws Exception {

        Book book1 = new Book("EMP_6953_2019", "Hibernate", "Java", "IGH Pubications", "English", 1232);
        String isbn = book1.getISBN();
        Book bookDetails = new Book("EMP_6953_2019", "Hibernate with JPA", "Java", "IGH Pubications", "English", 1532);
        when(librarianService.updateBook(isbn, bookDetails)).thenReturn(bookDetails);

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(put("/librarian/books/{isbn}", "EMP_6953_2019")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(jsonList.write(bookDetails).getJson())).andReturn()
                .getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(jsonList
                .write(new Book(bookDetails.getISBN(), bookDetails.getTitle(), bookDetails.getSubject(),
                        bookDetails.getPublisher(), bookDetails.getLanguage(), bookDetails.getNumberOfPages()))
                .getJson());

    }
```

**expected output:** 
"{"title":"Hibernate with JPA","subject":"Java","publisher":"IGH Pubications","language":"English","numberOfPages":1532,"isbn":"EMP_6953_2019"}"

**actual output:**
 ""

Comment: might be that your unmarshalled Book from json doesn't equal the initial Book object which gets sent over, which would cause the null return from librarianService.updateBook(..) and nothing in the response. Try debugging at the librarianService.updateBook(..) to verify

Comment: I tried to debug librarianService.updateBook() and it works fine, the error I think I am getting is on the following line. 
assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(jsonList
                .write(new Book(bookDetails.getISBN(), bookDetails.getTitle(), bookDetails.getSubject(),
                        bookDetails.getPublisher(), bookDetails.getLanguage(), bookDetails.getNumberOfPages()))
                .getJson());

Comment: Thanks, I manually implement the equals and hashCode methods and it works fine.